# ionic 2 searchbar placeholder colors

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to change the placeholder and the icon color for the ionic searchbar.
I am trying to override the scss variables in variables.scss file.
I am adding this

```
$searchbar-ios-input-placeholder-color: red;
$searchbar-ios-input-search-icon-color: red;
```

However it is not taking any change

Comment: Are you on ios though? Even ionic serve displays per specific platform

Comment: ios and other platforms. how can I make it general?

Comment: have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: yes.  $searchbar-md-input-text-color:red; or $searchbar-ios-input-placeholder-color: red; depends on the platform